# Plotting a time series with three lines in python

Tags: python, plot, time

I've been trying to plot a chart that would show three lines representing the investment in three sectors, named as "TELECOMUNICAÇÕES", "INFORMAÇÃO E COMUNICAÇÃO", and "FABRI. EQUIP..."

What I'm getting is a chart with a single line that is summing the investment in each subsector.

I know that this would take a pretty simple fix, but I really appreciate any help.

[Data visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHlee.png)

[Fail plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlTyS.png)

Please use this script as a sample:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ano = np.array(['1995-01-01','1995-01-01','1995-01-01',
            '1996-01-01','1996-01-01','1996-01-01',
            '1997-01-01','1997-01-01','1997-01-01',
            '1998-01-01','1998-01-01','1998-01-01'])
sub_cnae = np.array(['EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, ÓTICO', 'INFORMAÇÃO E 
COMUNICAÇÃO', 'TELECOMUNICAÇÕES',
                 'EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, ÓTICO', 'INFORMAÇÃO E COMUNICAÇÃO', 'TELECOMUNICAÇÕES',
                 'EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, ÓTICO', 'INFORMAÇÃO E COMUNICAÇÃO', 'TELECOMUNICAÇÕES',
                 'EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, ÓTICO', 'INFORMAÇÃO E COMUNICAÇÃO', 'TELECOMUNICAÇÕES'])
desembolso = np.array([54710927,10491526,34442570,
                   81075928,18151657,31442270,
                   58710927,1091526,34342570,
                   24710927,491526, 3442570])
df = pd.DataFrame({'ano' : ano, 'sub_cnae': sub_cnae, 'desembolso': desembolso})
```

Comment: Please provide a script and data we can test with

Comment: I've edited the question. Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the chart working:

- For each sub_cnae, filter the dataframe and plot the filtered results: `df[df['sub_cnae']==sc].plot(..)`
- To show multiple plots on the same figure, use the returned axis from the previous plot: `ax = df[...].plot(ax=ax,..)`

Here is the updated code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ano = np.array(['1995-01-01','1995-01-01','1995-01-01',
                 '1996-01-01','1996-01-01','1996-01-01',
                 '1997-01-01','1997-01-01','1997-01-01',
                 '1998-01-01','1998-01-01','1998-01-01'])
            
sub_cnae = np.array(['EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, OTICO', 'INFORMACAO E COMUNICACAO', 'TELECOMUNICACOES',
                     'EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, OTICO', 'INFORMACAO E COMUNICACAO', 'TELECOMUNICACOES',
                     'EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, OTICO', 'INFORMACAO E COMUNICACAO', 'TELECOMUNICACOES',
                     'EQUIP INFO, ELETRONICO, OTICO', 'INFORMACAO E COMUNICACAO', 'TELECOMUNICACOES'])
desembolso = np.array([54710927,10491526,34442570,
                       81075928,18151657,31442270,
                       58710927,1091526,34342570,
                       24710927,491526, 3442570])

subc = sub_cnae[:4]  # only need first 3 groups

df = pd.DataFrame({'ano' : ano, 'sub_cnae': sub_cnae, 'desembolso': desembolso}) # full dataframe

ax = None  # save previous axis for next plot
for i,sc in enumerate(sub_cnae[:3]):  # each line
  # filter dataframe and plot line
  ax = df[df['sub_cnae']==sc].plot(ax=ax, kind='line',x='ano',y='desembolso', label=subc[i], color=['red','green','blue'][i])

ax.set_xlabel('Ano')
ax.set_ylabel('Desembolso')
ax.set_title('Desembolsos')
plt.show()
```

Output

[image: PyPlot Chart]